# Improve performance in big project c# WPF XAML

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, web-services, xaml

We have a product (program) written in C# + WPF + XAML in our company. This is a fairly important program for us and it has been installed by many of our customers. But after switching to Framework 4.7.2, we noticed a strong performance degradation. We then changed to version 4.8, but the program still works quite slowly, especially the visual part.

In our program, we display data from a very large number of sensors (motion sensors, temperature, amount of light, etc.). We are constantly receiving new data that we process, save to the SQL Server 2014/2017 database, and then the client programs visualize this data.

The server part and communication, although complex, even works well on a not very powerful computer. But we have a very big problem with showing data on customer monitors.

The program is structured as follows: the client draws where he wants to see this data. For example, he has a black background and with lines he draws his factory. There are sensors in different places in this factory, he draws them in these places. Then he starts the scan and sees the result of the data where he drew the label. When there is little data, it is not very noticeable, but when there is a lot of data, moving the mouse between the data becomes inhibited, the client sees that the program is constantly slowing down and he needs to wait a few seconds, make some movement with the mouse and then again wait for the program to respond. If you do several things at once, then the program as if freezes. This is not so, but the feeling is that the program will now stop working.

I tried to use Debug and measurements of CPU and RAM but it practically did not help me in any way. Data is downloaded via web services from the server to the client program normally and takes up as much memory as needed. It’s hard to optimize it somehow. But when we start showing this data to the user, everything starts to work very badly. How to optimize data visualization so that the user continues to work calmly with the program? Will be glad to any advice.

What I did, which helped a bit to improve this virtualization in DataGrid tables. A little better for users, but this is not enough, you need something else, especially with the part that is drawn and shows labels with data in different places.

Comment: Please, share with us some details, like code and performance metrics, and make your problem more specific

Comment: What framework version were you on before?

Comment: @Edgaras First we use Framework 4.5, than 4.6 and work normally. But after 4.7.2 is going to bad performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience wpf is not suited for visualising large amount of data. It's fine for creating a fancy UI, but as the number of objects increase the performance drops dramatically. I tried everything from caching to freezing objects, and I concluded that I just chose the wrong technology. It doesn't utilise your GPU properly.

You can try converting to UWP, It might help.

Having that said, here are some tips you can also try:

> 1. Simplify your Visual Tree A common source of performance issues is a deep and complex layout. Keep your XAML markup as simple and shallow
>      as possible. When UI elements are drawn onscreen, a “layout pass” is
>      called twice for each element (a measure pass and an arrange pass).
>      The layout pass is a mathematically-intensive process—the larger the
>      number of children in the element, the greater the number of
>      calculations required.
> 2. Virtualize your ItemsControls As mentioned earlier, a complex and deep visual tree results in a larger memory footprint and slower
>      performance. ItemsControls usually increase performance problems with
>      deep visual trees because they are not virtualized. This means they
>      are constantly being created and destroyed for each item in the
>      control. Instead, use the VirtualizingStackPanel as the items host and
>      make use of the VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing and set the
>      VirtualizationMode to Recycling in order to reuse item containers
>      instead of creating new ones each time.
> 3. Favor StaticResources Over DynamicResources StaticResources provide values for any XAML property attribute by looking up a reference to an
>      already defined resource. Lookup behavior for that resource is the
>      same as a compile-time lookup. DynamicResources will create a
>      temporary expression and defer lookup for resources until the
>      requested resource value is required. Lookup behavior for that
>      resource is the same as a run-time lookup, which imposes a performance
>      impact. Always use a StaticResource whenever possible.
> 4. Opacity on Brushes Instead of Elements If you use a Brush to set the Fill or Stroke of an element, it is better to set the Opacity on
>      the Brush rather than setting the element’s Opacity property. When you
>      modify an element’s Opacity property, it can cause WPF to create
>      temporary surfaces which results in a performance hit.
> 5. Avoid Using Run to Set Text Properties Avoid using Runs within a TextBlock as this results in a much higher performance intensive
>      operation. If you are using a Run to set text properties, set those
>      directly on the TextBlock instead.
> 6. Favor StreamGeometries over PathGeometries The StreamGeometry object is a very lightweight alternative to a PathGeometry.
>      StreamGeometry is optimized for handling many PathGeometry objects. It
>      consumes less memory and performs much better when compared to using
>      many PathGeometry objects.
> 7. Use Reduced Image Sizes If your app requires the display of smaller thumbnails, consider creating reduced-sized versions of your images.
>      By default, WPF will load and decode your image to its full size. This
>      can be the source of many performance problems if you are loading full
>      images and scaling them down to thumbnail sizes in controls such as an
>      ItemsControl. If possible, combine all images into a single image,
>      such as a film strip composed of multiple images.
> 8. Lower the BitMapScalingMode By default, WPF uses a high-quality image re-sampling algorithm that can sometimes consume system
>      resources which results in frame rate degradation and causes
>      animations to stutter. Instead, set the BitMapScalingMode to
>      LowQuality to switch from a “quality-optimized” algorithm to a
>      “speed-optimized” algorithm.
> 9. Use and Freeze Freezables A Freezable is a special type of object that has two states: unfrozen and frozen. When you freeze an object
>      such as a Brush or Geometry, it can no longer be modified. Freezing
>      objects whenever possible improves the performance of your application
>      and reduces its memory consumption.
> 10. Fix your Binding Errors Binding errors are the most common type of performance problem in WPF apps. Every time a binding error occurs,
>       your app takes a perf hit and as it tries to resolve the binding and
>       writes the error out to the trace log. As you can imagine, the more
>       binding errors you have the bigger the performance hit your app will
>       take. Take the time to find and fix all your binding errors. Using a
>       RelativeSource binding in DataTemplates is a major culprit in binding
>       error as the binding is usually not resolved properly until the
>       DataTempate has completed its initialization. Avoid using
>       RelativeSource.FindAncestor at all costs. Instead, define an attached
>       property and use property inheritance to push values down the visual
>       tree instead of looking up the visual tree.
> 11. Avoid Databinding to the Label.Content Property If you are using a Label to data bind to a String property, this will result in poor
>       performance. This is because each time the String source is updated,
>       the old string object is discarded, and a new String is created. If
>       the Content of the Label is simple text, replace it with a TextBlock
>       and bind to the Text property instead.
> 12. Bind ItemsControls to IList instead of IEnumerable When data binding an ItemsControl to an IEnumerable, WPF will create a wrapper
>       of type IList which negatively impacts performance with the
>       creation of a second object. Instead, bind the ItemsControl directly
>       to an IList to avoid the overhead of the wrapper object.
> 13. Use the NeutralResourcesLanguage Attribute Use the NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute to tell the ResourceManager what the
>       neutral culture is and avoid unsuccessful satellite assembly lookups.
> 14. Load Data on Separate Threads A very common source of performance problems, UI freezes, and apps that stop responding is how you load
>       your data. Make sure you are asynchronously loading your data on a
>       separate thread as to not overload the UI thread. Loading data on the
>       UI thread will result in very poor performance and an overall bad
>       end-user experience. Multi-threading should be something every WPF
>       developer is using in their applications.
> 15. Beware of Memory Leaks Memory leaks are the number one cause of performance problems in most WPF applications. They are easy to have
>       but can be difficult to find. For example, using the
>       DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged can cause the WPF
>       framework to take a strong reference to the source of the event that
>       isn’t removed until you manually call
>       DependencyPropertyDescriptor.RemoveValueChanged. If your views or
>       behaviors rely on events being raised from an object or ViewModel
>       (such as INotifyPropertyChanged), subscribe to them weakly or make
>       sure you are manually unsubscribing. Also, if you are binding to
>       properties in a ViewModel which does not implement
>       INotifyPropertyChanged, chances are you have a memory leak.
>
> Finally, a bonus tip. Sometimes when you have a performance problem it
>   can be very difficult to identify what exactly is causing the issue. I
>   suggest using an application performance profiler to help identify
>   where these performance bottlenecks are occurring in your code base.
>   There are a lot of profiler options available to you. Some are paid,
>   and some are free. The one I personally use the most is the Diagnosis
>   Tools built directly into Visual Studio 2019.
>   Blockquote

Source: https://dzone.com/articles/15-wpf-performance-tips-for-2019

Comment: i dont know where do you come with this story, we build a 20M $ app for customer with WPF including automation and video surveillance with a very loaded interface that split over 4 screens, and have 10 clustered servers, if you have performance issue check your code.

Comment: I'm not talking about a loaded interface, I'm not talking about having to manipulate thousands of StreamGeometry objects. The profit of your business is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Szesan I go to work in that points. May be it help me. Thank you